# Focus on first visible and empty select/dropdown using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, html-select

I do some validation for the required fields and then I want to focus on the first visible textarea or textbox or select.

The the following code, works fine for textarea and textbox but not for select. How can I make a check for an empty select in the following jquery statement. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$("textarea:empty:visible,input[value='']:visible,select option[value='']:visible").first().focus();
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zUw36/2/).

Comment: problem is you are trying to set focus on option, not select. BTW, not sure option can be :visible

Comment: That was my try, I was not sure how to check for the empty value other than that. I also tried `select:empty:visible` also `select[value='']` they didn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.filter()`

```
$("textarea:empty:visible,input[value='']:visible,select").filter(function () {
    if ($(this).is('select')) {
        if (this.value === "") {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}).first().focus();
```

Demo `----->` http://jsfiddle.net/zUw36/8/

Comment: ...but this will always select the first dropdown ignoring empty textarea and textbox which are placed before dropdown. I mean, if the first textarea and dropdown are empty, the focus should be on the first control in the form i.e. textarea.

Comment: This works great! So, there is no way to do it in one line like what we can do with textarea and input? :D